Comparing data from two dataframes and filtering them
I've recently worked on a project in which I use pandas dataframes to store data. I've currently got two dataframes containing odds from sportsbookies for football games, with this data I want to compare the odds from both bookies and replace the lowest odd with the highest. In attempts to achieve this I seem to get stuck. I've even gotten so far as to having 2 if statements and 5 for loops nested inside each other and I still can't seem to make it work. My code currently (desperately) looks like this:
for cols in df.columns:
    for colus in df1.columns:
        if cols == colus:
            for game in df.index:
                for games in df1.index:
                    for odd in df[f'{cols}']:
                        for odds in df1[f'{cols}']:
                            if fuzz.ratio(game, games) > 90 and odd > odds:
                                print(odd)
                            else:
                                pass
        else:
            pass

As you can see my code just gets messier and messier and I can't seem to find a solution. Here's a small part of the dataframes i'm using
https://i.sstatic.net/uw1HJ.png (df1)
https://i.sstatic.net/dRtZ6.png (df)
As you can see I'm in desperate need of help and would really appreciate some! <3

Your question is lacking a [mre]

I think you should refactor code a bit. For example in the begining you are using statement 'cols=colus'. Which means that start of the code should be:
for cols in df.columns:
    if cols not in df1:
      # skip processing if column not present.
       continue
    for game in df.index:
      ...


@mozway, sorry about that. What info should i add to my question?

Have you read the link in my comment? For starters images are not reproducible.

Actually would like to show an example how to adjust your code and get rid of cycle that looks very messy:
# separately get matching columns (you may vectorize this)
same_cols = []
for colname in df.columns:
    if colname in df1:
      same_cols.append(colname)
    

# because fuzzy.ration is very time consuming calculation
# I would reco to have it before iteration through columns 
for game in df.index:
    # to speed up 'fuzz.ratio' you can try to implement it with KDtrees
    for game1 in df1.index:
        if fuzz.ratio(game, game1) <= 90:
            # use 'continue' to skip pairs that you don't want to process
            continue

        # iterate over matching cols (can be vectorized
        for colname in same_cols:
            odd = df.loc[game, colname]
            odd1 = df1.loc[game1, colname]
            if odd>odd1:
                print (odd)


I'd break this into chunks,
Step 1, fuzzy match the games give them a game_id
*I'll let you work this bit out
Step 2, merge the two dataframes together on the game id
df = df.merge(df1, on='game_id', how='outer')

Step 3, Take the min/max of the each of the two odds columns in turn
df['min_home_odds'] = df[['min_home_x','min_home_y']].min(axis=1)

